# ‎SSIS/SQL Server Agent execution issue‎

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

[image: failed to connect]

Here is a description of the issue and a couple of screen prints.

SSIS/SQL Server Agent execution issue

I have a package which executes without issue in SSIS Visual Studio debug mode, but when the package is deployed to the server and SQL Server Agent, the package fails with errors. I have searched online for answers and found a few but none have worked, including creating a proxy. The package contains 2 OLE connections to 2 different servers. If only 1 connection is used, it works without issue. If both are used, the job fails. I am attaching the screen print for a couple of the errors. This is all within Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2016.

When the package runs from a SQL Agent job step it fails with:

```
 Login failed for user 'REGISNET\RUW4-100$'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your error messages as text. Error messages in images aren't searchable so don't help other people experiencing similar issues.

Comment: The Execution Report from SSMS is great until you need to copy the text out of it (not an option). So, take that "Operation ID" 597 in this case and query against the SSISDB with it `SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.operation_id = 597 ` If there are many results, distill it down to just errors by adding this to the where clause `AND OM.message_type = 120`

Answer (score 1):

> Login failed for user 'REGISNET\RUW4-100$'

Since SQL Agent is running with the default virtual account, any connections to other servers using Windows Auth will be made using the machine account.

You need to create a login on the target database for the machine account and grant it sufficient permissions for whatever the SSIS package is doing with that data source.

On the target database run

```
create login [REGISNET\RUW4-100$] from windows;
create user [REGISNET\RUW4-100$] for login [REGISNET\RUW4-100$]; 
create role etl_user;
alter role etl_user add member [REGISNET\RUW4-100$];
grant select to etl_user;  --or whatever permissions are needed
```

Comment: Thank you so much, these commands worked!!